# Origin of the Universe

Tags: universe

I heard on a you tube video that a new theory came out in 2015 . The theory is that there was no "Big Bang" and that the Universe has no beginning .

Comment: What is the question here?

Comment: Well, the question is if this is true or not ? If there was no "Big Bang" then what is causing the Universe to expand ? Don't our observations point towards a "Big Bang" having occurred ?

Comment: We need more details about then theory, then - and I should add that the idea of an eternal universe is far from new.

Answer (score 1):

Not entirely sure as to what question you're asking exactly but many theories of the origin of the universe have risen for many decades now. But as you would know, the Big Bang theory is the most accepted one. Since I'm typing this from my phone, I won't go into detail but I did once write an essay on this. 
There are obviously parties that are against the theory and parties that are for it. But some of the other theories of origination sometimes fail to cover certain aspects or even suggest of multiple dimensions beyond what we already believe exists. 
But none are as well researched or factual as the Big Bang theory. 
Hope that helps :)